# How to make even animations with sprite sheets in Unity 5?

Tags: unity, 2d, spritesheet

When importing a sprite sheet into Unity and dividing it up, what is the best way to do so to ensure that your animation works smoothly? Is there a mathematical formula for dividing the spritesheet evenly, and should you use Grid By Cell Size or Grid By Cell Count?

Also, can the free version of TexturePacker help with organizing sprites for Unity? Or are there other alternatives to the software?

Comment: I'm confused by the context of your first question. Ultimately, there's only two ways you could reach any conclusion that there was a mathamtical formula you would need to use; either you have not looked into using sprite sheets, yet (the basic tutorials tell you how to do this), or your misunderstanding is rooted in *Mathematics*, not game development. *There is nothing wrong with that*, for the scope of GameDevSE, but a mathematics question should probably be posted on the Mathematics Exchange.

Comment: You also appear to be asking another question, that seems related only in topic; you would be better posting additional questions *separately*, unless they are directly involved.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve right now? If your animation is currently not working "smoothly," try showing us an example of what it's doing now, and how you've set it up, and we can try to diagnose the issue and suggest fixes. There's no one best answer for what type of slicing to use - it will depend on how you've authored and laid out your sprite sheet.

Answer (score 1):

No maths formula is needed, as long as you decompress the sprite sheet you can use automatic splicing, or experiment with different x and y numbers on the grid by cell size and grid by cell count until you're happy.

As for animation there is a very good animation and animator within Unity, I suggest you look at the Unity Documentation to get to grips with it(it is a bit big to put in a post).

Useful links:

[Animator Controller](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html)

[Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimatinSection.html)

Hopes this helps.